# Is YARN responsible of distributing the data over HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I'm a beginner on Hadoop and I can't understand how we distribute data over HDFS:

```
1- Manually   
2- with YARN
3- other ways to do it
4- Automatically
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is automatically replicated when it is added to HDFS. Simply executing the command

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <local-file> <hdfs-location>
```

will place a file on the HDFS with a replication factor of 3 (by default). Replication is completely automated and abstracted away from the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how the data are distributed over nodes (automatically or via yarn or manually) @Ben Waston

Comment: It's automatic; YARN doesn't come into it. If you have rack awareness enabled then data will be added across racks to ensure it's available if one entire rack dies.